# Apache / Nginx / Varnish - GZIP does not work on css, js

Tags: apache, nginx, gzip, varnish, deflate

My current setup is as following:
Apache -> Nginx -> Varnish
running on Ubuntu

apache2.conf: h**p://pastebin.com/A3wehAbe

.htaccess: h**p://pastebin.com/Yre4hdSy (edited to allow deflate)

nginx.conf: h**p://pastebin.com/6X59CTAr (gzip enabled)

varnish: default settings

My problem is, it seems that GZIP only works with html content, not css or js.

I tested GZIP with this tool at:
http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php

1. h**p://rentsites.com.au
   result: compressed yes

   > status HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   >   server  nginx/0.7.65
   >   content-type    text/html;
   >   charset=UTF-8
   >   x-powered-by    PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.22
   >   x-pingback  h**p://rentsites.com.au/xmlrpc.php
   >   vary    Accept-Encoding
   >   content-encoding    gzip
   >   content-length  2281
   >   accept-ranges   bytes
   >   date    Mon, 13 Jan 201400:50:26 GMT
   >   x-varnish   785049695 785049694
   >   age 13
   >   via 1.1 varnish
   >   connection  close
2. h**p://rentsites.com.au/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js
   result: compressed NO

   > status HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   >   server  nginx/0.7.65
   >   content-type    application/x-javascript
   >   last-modified   Wed, 21 Aug 2013 15:41:10 GMT
   >   expires Mon, 12 Jan 2015 23:17:22 GMT
   >   cache-control   max-age=31536000, public
   >   pragma  public
   >   content-length  93085
   >   accept-ranges   bytes
   >   date    Mon, 13 Jan 2014 00:27:30 GMT
   >   x-varnish   785049693 785049631
   >   age 4208
   >   via 1.1 varnish
   >   connection  close
3. h**p://rentsites.com.au/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/genericons/genericons.css
   result: compressed NO

   > status HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   >   server  nginx/0.7.65
   >   content-type    text/css
   >   last-modified   Tue, 12 Nov 2013 18:38:10 GMT
   >   expires Mon, 12 Jan 2015 23:16:50 GMT
   >   cache-control   max-age=31536000, public
   >   pragma  public
   >   content-length  22680
   >   accept-ranges   bytes
   >   date    Mon, 13 Jan 2014 00:52:38 GMT
   >   x-varnish   785049696 785049621
   >   age 5748
   >   via 1.1 varnish
   >   connection  close

Please help. Thanks for reading.

Comment: you didn't share the 1 config file that actually matters, the virtual host file, I would assume yours exist inside `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` is there a file other than `default`? if not then please share `default`, because I don't think wordpress would work without special virtual host settings

Comment: Please don't duplicate your questions on serverfault and stackoverflow. Duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/566807/apache-nginx-varnish-gzip-does-not-work-on-css-js

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady: here's the content of 'example':
http://pastebin.com/1521fcRr

Comment: Ok I just noticed that the gzip is enabled on the `http` block of nginx.conf, so I think this might be `varnish`'s fault, but I can't tell for sure if it supports gzip by default or not

Comment: Varnish only does caching, I dont think it has anything to do with gzip.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that we need to add this to .htaccess:

AddType text/css .css
AddType text/javascript .js